# How to auto login OpenVPN without the GUI(I unchecked GUI upon installation)

Tags: openvpn

I don't want the GUI to be shown so i unchecked it in the installation process.

I want to send like --connect client.ovpn
It doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

What'd I do:

Pre-configure OpenVPN (with GUI) with the user configuration file that was downloaded after installing the OpenVPN server.

Add OpenVPN to Windows Startup.

Comment: I am using windows, and i dont want the gui to be shown in the tray. I just want fully command in cmd to connect disconnect without start up logon.

Comment: In that case, please navigate to "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config" or wherever you've installed OpenVPN. Drop the User Conf file there and then make sure that the OpenVPN service startup is set to automatic in Services.msc

Comment: Sorry but, i want it to be started by my app not the start up.